# Rosbag record does not record the first messages

Tags: ros, rosbag

I am having a problem with ROS rosbag.
I have a python script that generates and publishes messages. I try to record them with `rosbag record` but the generated rosbag does not seem to contain the first messages.

I have done the following:

1. Run the script while in other terminal I have `rostopic echo /the_message` and I can see that *all messages are being correctly generated* --> so it is not a problem of the script
2. Run *first* (just in case some "initialization time" is needed) in one terminal `rosbag record -O data.bag /the_message` and then in other terminal the script. I got the bag file correctly. But then when playing the bag with `rosbag play --clock data.bag` and `rostopic echo /the_message` in other terminal I got only the messages from the third or fourth message. *Never the first message*

What could be happening? and How can I ensure the recording takes place including the first messages?

Comment: A little more information is probably needed because this isn't a common problem with `rosbag record`. What is the message type the script is publishing? Also at what rate? Have you tried verifying this isn't a system problem by doing something such as: attempting to record a single std_msg from `rostopic pub` such as `rostopic pub --once /dummy_topic std_msgs/String hello`?

Comment: it is a ROS Image message.I will  check out the rest when I get to the office.  About the other, let me see if I understood. You mean using `rostopic pub` to publish once *while* rosbag recording and see if it records it?

Comment: `rospy.Rate(10)`.  I wrote my own script to record rosbags and now it records all messages. `rosbag record` misses 3 messages. Now I have to try if it works from launch files